# spark error and hadoop err

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop-hp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hp/filecache/28/__spark_libs__5301477595013800425.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hp/hadoop-2.7.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/04/06 21:28:08 WARN SparkConf: spark.master yarn-cluster is deprecated in Spark 2.0+, please instead use "yarn" with specified deploy mode.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hp/data/gTree.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.loadGenTree(kAnonymity_spark.java:50)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.run(kAnonymity_spark.java:391)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.main(kAnonymity_spark.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hp/data/t1_resizingBy_10000.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.loadData(kAnonymity_spark.java:149)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.run(kAnonymity_spark.java:392)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.main(kAnonymity_spark.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
18/04/06 21:28:39 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.performAnonymity(kAnonymity_spark.java:365)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.run(kAnonymity_spark.java:394)
    at com.exsparkbasic.ExSparkBasic.kAnonymity_spark.main(kAnonymity_spark.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
```

/home/hp/data/gTree.txt exists and has been added to the Hadoop file system. But I still get an error.

Among the Java code in the jar file

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream ("/home/hp/data/gTree.txt");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader (stream);
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader (reader);
```

An error occurs in this part.

When using Hadoop yarn clusters, should not I set the path value of the file?

```
hp@master:~$ ls -al /home/hp/data/gTree.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hp hp 419 11월 16 16:17 /home/hp/data/gTree.txt

hp@master:~$ hadoop fs -ls /home/hp/data/gTree.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 hp supergroup        419 2018-04-06 21:06 /home/hp/data/gTree.txt
```

Comment: Not really clear why you're using Spark if you're not using any Spark methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is occurring since you have specifically referred to the file `/home/hp/data/gTree.txt` using `FileInputStream` which reads from the local file system and not from hdfs.

The exception is encountered since Spark application code running in data nodes are trying to read this file from local file system.

Depending on your use case, you may have to use `hdfs://<NN:port>/<File Name>` to refer to the file. 
You most probably want to do `SparkContext.textFile()`. Refer this [example](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html).